# How to set param values in a Jenkins Pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a few existing jobs created by the Jenkins UI and i'm trying to run them as part of a pipeline script.

The problem i'm facing is that in most jobs i have "Active Choices Reactive Parameter" parameters which is being populated by a scriptler script and requires a value selection to build the job.

My goal is to automatically build the job and to set by code a test value but everything i tried until now failed. 
for example:

```
 stage('Test') {
 build job: 'Test-regression', parameters: [
 [$class: 'WHideParameterValue', name: 'envListDb', value: 'TestEnvironmentListByOperator'],
 string(name: 'Operator', value: 'TestOp'),
 validatingString(name: 'OperatorValidation', value: 'TestOp'),  
 string(name: 'Environment', value: 'Test'),
 validatingString(name: 'EnvironmentValidation', value: 'Test')
 ]
}
```

When running this i got "the parameter 'Operator' did not have the type expected by Test-regression. Converting to Active Choices Reactive Parameter" so as mentioned i guess the problem is not having an actual selected value for the build itself.

I might be doing it the wrong way but i would appreciate if anyone has an idea which would spare me the need to create a new layout just for the pipeline testing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand here `Test-regression` is a standalone pipeline with input params `Operator` and `Environment`. You want to invoke `Test-regression` pipeline in another pipeline for which you have shared the code.

I had a similar requirement and following code worked for me. I have modified the code to suit your requirement:

```
env.TestOp="your_val_1";
env.Test="your_val_2";

stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                build job: 'Test-regression', parameters: [
                string(name: 'Operator', value: "${TestOp}"),
                string(name: 'Environment', value: "${Test}")
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: HI,
Thanks for your answer but it seems like i'm getting to the same result:
The parameter 'Operator' did not have the type expected by Test-regression.. Converting to Active Choices Reactive Parameter.
I think i might have to duplicate the job and change the relevant fields to be strings

Comment: I've accepted your answer since the issue seems to have been my validation string variable defined as validatingString instead of string.
I still have the conversion message but it's working so i'll let it be. Thanks